# Sound applet has dissappeared

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, gnome-panel, applet

I recently removed and reinstalled pulseaudio and now I can't get my sound applet back on my panel.

Any ideas how to get it back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try installing/reinstalling the package indicator-sound:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

Also, make sure that PulseAudio Sound System is ticked in System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications.

Answer (score 3):

This is bundled into the **Indicator Applet**. Restore it as follows:

1. Right-click on the menu bar.
2. Select `Add to Panel...`
3. Select `Indicator Applet` (or `Audio Mixer`).
4. Click `Add`.

The applet appears on the bar.

Comment: That didn't work, I already have my Indicator applet open on the panel. Its properly dissapeared. Is there an option in gconf-editor to turn it off or something as this is what i think could have happened

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. :( If you do a `ps ax | grep indicator-applet` does it show an active process for it?  Try killing it `kill -9 1234` (where 1234 is the pid)... Does that prompt you to reload the applet?

Answer (score 1):

You may also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and launch `gnome-volume-control-applet` command.

Comment: That would be the old one without music player controls etc.