# Volume adjuster and icon at the top of the screen is missing

Tags: sound, icons, volume-control

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98P5x.png) to see the picture.
As you can see there is no sound icon and I cant adjust the sound without going into the sound settings every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lauch it in your terminal

```
gnome-sound-applet &
```

FMI see [Sound applet has dissappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272/sound-applet-has-dissappeared)

Comment: I don't know how to install the package "indicator-sound".

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install indicator-sound`

Comment: ok. What do I do now. Restart?

Comment: run `killall unity-panel-service`, to make the change take effect.